# How to register checkboxes in database?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

i want to make a script in php, that registers an email in the database, and they have 2 checkboxes below, option1 and option2, I got the first part done.Managed to make the script connect and register the email in the database but I have no idea how to register the checkboxes aswell.Any ideas?

```
<?php
    include_once('mysql.php');
    db_connect();

    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscribe(email) VALUES('$email')"))
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('Abonat cu succes');</script>
        <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('Va rog introduceti un email valid');</script>
        <?php
 }
}
 ?>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="" class="bk">
  <fieldset>
  <p align="center" class="txt">Subscribe E-mail:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" size="20" class="txtbox">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" class="button"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="evenimente" value="Evenimente">Evenimente
    <input type="checkbox" name="anunturi" value="Anunturi">Anunturi
   </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The checkboxes have the value 0 by default in the table,I want to give them the value 1 if they are checked and 0 if not.

Comment: Did you even try ? As a side note, unchecked checkboxes aren't even sent through the POST request...

Comment: If one types `alala@dot.com'); DROP TABLE subscribe; --` in your email field, it'll destroy your system. Look for SQL injections and don't use `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Echo out your POST array to see what the variable / values are and work from there

Comment: The script is not finish yet, I will include a sanitize and a validation script aswell, for now I run it in localhost for testing.But thanks for the advice,I apreciate it!

Comment: if checkbox is checked it will give the value of that, if not, it will not get post and you will not see that index in `$_POST` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecked checkboxes aren't sent with POST/GET requests, only checked ones:

**UNCHECKED:**

```
Array
(
)
```

**CHECKED:**

```
Array
(
    [checkme] => on
)
```

You'll have to verify for the field existence in `$_POST` superglobal.

```
if (isset($_POST['checkme'])) {
    // do stuff when checked
} else {
    // do stuff when don't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get the value in `$_POST['evenimente']` and `$_POST['anunturi']`. You can check them in php script and save in database

check them in php means: we will not find that key in `$_POST` if they are not checked and so we can check for `isset($_POST[key])` and decide the value for database

Comment: What value will be sent if `evenimente` is unchecked?

Comment: 0 or false. You can echo and see.

Comment: Then you echo it. Did you test it? I really doubt you're going to find 0 or false there.

Comment: you will not find that name in post array itself.

Comment: dont give guess answers.

Comment: yes we will not find that key in $_POST and so we can check for isset($_POST[key]) and decide

Comment: have you added this part in your answer??